# How do I build a script shell to send cmd via telnet and log only results?

Tags: bash, shell, script, expect

I would like to make a shell script that can call a range of IPs via telnet, to send a command, and write the result to a file.

Comment: windows has telnet -f , linux has this way.. the script command or the tee command http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121241/can-i-grep-telnet-command-output

Answer (score 0):

ssh is easier than telnet:

```
for host in host1 host2 host3; do
    ssh user@host remote_command with args 
done > result.file
```

For password-less login, set up ssh keys

---

This will have bugs, but something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
exp_internal 1
set out [open "results.txt" w]
foreach ip $argv {
    spawn telnet $ip
    expect "password: "
    send "$password\r"
    expect "% "          ;# this is the prompt, adjust to suit
    sent "the command\r"
    expect -re "([01,]+).*% "
    puts $out "$ip=$expect_out(1,string)"
    send exit
    expect eof
    exp_close
    wait
}
close $out
```

Comment: Thanks, but my devices support only telnet. I must send this command: status. The result can be: 0,0,0,0,0,0 or 1,1,1,1,1 or mix combination I want put only the result in a file. Is it possibile? Like this:

192.168.1.1 = 0,0,0,0,0,0 192.168.1.2 = 1,0,0,0,0,0 192.168.1.3 = 0,1,0,0,0,0 192.168.1.4 = 0,0,1,0,0,0 192.168.1.5 = 0,1,0,0,1,0